# ob_start problem with PHP code

Tags: php, ob-start

Ok, I can't come to grips with this ob_start and ob_end_clean code...

Basically, I am trying to output PHP code within a page section.

Here is my source code:

```
$content = trim(html_entity_decode($context['page_data']['body'], ENT_QUOTES, $context['character_set']));
$content = trim($content, '<?php');
$content = trim($content, '?>');

function dream_error_handler($output)
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    $output = "";
    if (!empty($error))
        foreach ($error as $info => $string)
            if ($info == 'message')
                $output .= $string;

    return $output;
}

ob_start('dream_error_handler');
eval($content);
$code = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$context['page_data']['body'] = $code;
```

Now, in the template function, I am using this:

```
global $context;

echo '
                <div class="cat_bar">
                    <h3 class="catbg">
                        ', $context['page_data']['title'], '
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <span class="upperframe"><span></span></span>
                    <div class="roundframe">
                        ', $context['page_data']['body'], '
                    </div>
                <span class="lowerframe"><span><!-- // --></span></span>
            ';
```

So why am I getting this error message?

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server
>   Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was
>   attempting to fulfill the request.

What am I doing wrong here?  The $context['page_data']['body'] has valid PHP code, a simple `echo 'Hello World';` but it gives me this 500 Internal Server Error.  Why?

Comment: You should use `.` instead of `,` in the template to concatenate strings. Take a look at the Apache error log, too.

Comment: @Boldewyn the [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) construct accept multiple parameters, although the docs state that parenthesis should be used in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `eval()` shouldn't be called for a string containing `<?php ?>` as it is assumed that the contents of the string itself is pure PHP code. So you should be able to remove the two `trim()` calls you're making in addition to using @Boldewyn's suggestion.

Comment: Well than what should I use instead of `eval()` to output the PHP?  `echo $content;` is no good.

Comment: I'm saying that you can still use `eval()`, just don't add the `<?php` and `?>` to the `$content` variable as the function assumes everything you pass to it is already PHP code.

Comment: Ok, removed it, I follow you now.  Figured out the problem, didn't have `error_get_last()` function defined anywhere.